# How can send a list/vector/array of dataframes to a function in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to pass several dataframes, each of different dimensions to another function and process each of these data frames one by one. How should I do this.

I tried

```
frame <- c(df1,df2,df3...)

p <- function(frame) {
  for(i in 1:seq_along(frame) {
     do_something(frame[i])
     .....
   }
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: care to elaborate on `but this doesn't work.`?

Comment: Try using a `list` and `lappy`; something like `frame <- list(...); lapply(frame, do_something)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note the difference between vectors and lists in R. Vectors hold atomic (simple) objects of identical classes (ie, all numeric, all character etc). lists can hold objects of heterogeneous type. Lists can also hold other lists (vectors cannot be nested).

In R, data.frames are really just fancy lists, so if you want to have a collection of them, you'll need a list of data.frames

```
frame <- list(df1,df2,df3...)
```

When you are extracting objects from a list, you need to use `[[ ]]` to get the element rather than `[ ]` which is just use to subset a list (and it will always return a list). So your loop should be written as

```
p <- function(frame) {
  for(i in 1:seq_along(frame)) {
     do_something(frame[[i]])
   }
}
```

But rarely do we need to write looks like that in R. It's often better to just `lapply` over a list

```
p <- function(frame) {
    lapply(frame, do_something)
}
```

but ultimately that depends on what your code is really doing.